# Laravel - Pass object through view and use in blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Basically, I've a simple  'exp' column in my database and I want to use a function 'showLevel()' where I can pass in `Auth::user->username` as the argument instead of a static name. I'm struggling with how I can use either a function in an echo on my template or with an object.

```
public function index()
{
    $users = User::all();

    $level = $this->showLevel('test');

    return view('home')->with('users', $users)->with('showLevel', $level);
}

public function showLevel($username) {

    $level = DB::table('users')->where('username', $username)->pluck('exp');

    if ($level < 500) {
        return 1;
    } else if ($level > 500 && $level < 1000) {
        return 2;
    } else if ($level > 1000 && $level < 1500) {
        return 3;
    } else if ($level > 1500 && $level < 2000) {
        return 4;
    } else if ($level > 2000 && $level < 2500) {
        return 5;
    } else if ($level > 2500) {
        return 'MAX';
    }

}
```

I tried creating an object in home.blade.php.

```
$level = new HomeController;
$level->showLevel(Auth::user->username);
```

But that didn't seem to work. Can you pass objects in blade? I've been trying to look this up myself but maybe I'm wording it wrong. I'm stuck!

I basically want to be able to do something like `{{ showLevel(Auth::user->username); }}` in my home.blade.php to echo the level that's returned from the function.

Comment: I would put the level on the user model like this: https://gist.github.com/flackend/117886bfbc7df988364e

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
use Auth;
$level = new HomeController();
$data = $level->showLevel(Auth::user()->username);
```

and Return Blade::

```
 return view('home')->with(['data'=>$data]);
```

Now, In Your Blade You Can Use $data

Comment: Tried it and I got "Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth' not found", am I not inheriting something to my class?

Comment: Ah, duh! I'm getting an underfined variable though now when I try and do {{ $data }}?

Comment: use    <?php echo $data ?>

Comment: Isn't that what {{ }} is in blade? An echo statement? EDIT: Nevermind got it! I copied yours exactly and you had [] squar brakets!

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can pass an object to blade. You use the compact method to achieve that:

```
return view('home')->with(compact('users'));
```

In your blade you can access users like this:

```
@if ($users)
   @foreach($users as $user)
      {{ $user->name }}
   @endforeach
@endif
```

Answer (score 1):

```
return view('home', compact('users'));
```

than you can foreach it on your blade.php

Answer (score 0):

The shorthand for compact and with would be:

```php
return view('home', ['data' => $data,...]);
```

This is works just fine for all of my views where this is needed.